# How to use axis2 code generator?

Tags: java, apache, apache-axis

I want to build a web service client and after some research i tried to use axis2Java in Eclipse.

I wonder how this works, I have the WSDL of the web service I want to access and i went through all the steps in the wizard of code generator, including the success popup at the end.

I thought it would generate some Java classes in order to be used in the construction of the SOAP request to the web service but I don't seem to find any.

I wonder what am I doing wrong with this? Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me that you only imported the WSDL-file but did not create the Web Service client itself.

Here is what you have to do to make this work in **Eclipse**:

**First open the "Import"-Dialog**

- File => Import => General => File System
- Click "Next"

**Select the WSDL you want to import**

- Click the "Browse"-Button next to the "From directory" drop down menu.
- Select the folder which contains the WSDL and click "OK"
- Check the WSDL file in the right window (Make sure the file has the ending ".wsdl" so Eclipse recognizes it as such)
- Click "Finish"

**Create a Webservice Client**

- File => New => Other => Web Services => Web Service Client
- Click "Next"
- Click the "Browse"-Button next to the "Service definition" drop down menu
- Click another "Browse"-Button next to the URI-Textfield
- In the Resource browser open your project and select the previously imported WSDL-file and click "OK"
- Click "OK" and "Finish"

Now the classes should be available in your src-directory.

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you a lot for the amazing tip!

Answer (score 0):

I had done this by using command line,which will generate stubs using specific command in Axis below was the tutorial I followed:

http://www.digizol.com/2008/07/web-service-axis-tutorial-client-server.html